# Angular JS ng-show and ng-if in one html i tag

Tags: html, angularjs, mobile

This is my code.

```
<i class="errorfield" ng-if="rigst.secretans === rigst.password" ng-show="(registration.secretanswer.$dirty || submitted) && registration.secretanswer.$invalid">
   <span>
      <img class="error" src="./img/errorimage.png"  />     
   </span>
</i>
```

I want to put angularjs ng-show and ng-if combine in one line to produce error on an input element.

Comment: you forgot to attach the code snippet

Comment: You also forgot to ask a question.

Comment: What does that mean "combine in one line"? They are different attributes - do you just want to use one of them with an AND?

Comment: The problem might very well be that the amount of logic inside your expression becomes too complex. You can use some basic expressions, but don't try to do complex logic. I suggest using ng-show="shouldBeShown(rigst)"> and creating a $scope.shouldBeShown(item) function that handles the logic for you, including the if and returns a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

I guess any of the following will work for you. ng-if modifies the dom while ng-show doesnot. Choose accordingly.

```
<i class="errorfield"
ng-if="(rigst.secretans === rigst.password)&&((registration.secretanswer.$dirty || submitted) && registration.secretanswer.$invalid)">
<span> <img class="error" src="./img/errorimage.png" />
</span>
</i>

<i class="errorfield"
ng-show="(rigst.secretans === rigst.password)&&((registration.secretanswer.$dirty || submitted) && registration.secretanswer.$invalid)">
<span> <img class="error" src="./img/errorimage.png" />
</span>
</i>

<i class="errorfield" ng-if="rigst.secretans === rigst.password">
<div
    ng-show="(registration.secretanswer.$dirty || submitted) && registration.secretanswer.$invalid">
    <span> <img class="error" src="./img/errorimage.png" />
    </span>
</div>
</i>
```